# Tengo una duda para redireccionar a una pagina si es el Admin y a otra si es Usuario normal. JSP Y SERVLET

Tags: java, jsp

Tengo este codoigo pero siempre me redirige hacia index aunque el usuario sea Administrador...

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {


    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String usuario = request.getParameter("usuario");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");         


    UsuarioDao co = new UsuarioDao();
    if(co.auteticacion(usuario, pass)) {            
        Usuario user = co.obtenerUsuarioNombre(usuario);
        if(user.getUsuario() == "Administrador") {
            response.sendRedirect("aAdministracion.jsp");
        }
        request.getSession().setAttribute("ape", user.getApellido());
        request.getSession().setAttribute("usuario", user.getUsuario());
        request.getSession().setAttribute("pass", user.getPass());
        request.getSession().setAttribute("user", user.getNombre());
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }else {         
        response.sendRedirect("indexx.jsp");

    }
}
```

Comment: Ya lo he solucionado era que en vez de == los tenia que comparar con equals!

Comment: @LauraFernandez cuando hagas comparaciones entre Strings trata de hacerlo siempre con `equals`